# Citrus Payment gateway On IOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, payment-gateway

I am working on a project which contains a module of  payment by using Citrus.I already implemented in the IOS Application. when i am going to submit my App to Appstore.IS i need to Provide any card details to apple.iIs the Apple Will accept the citrus payments.

> Here the Payments  will be used to pay the bills for Cabs.

Comment: To achieve this, you need to be PCI DSS compliance buddy...!!!

Answer (score 1):

no need to save the card details in anywhere inside the app or no need to share outside the app also. if u unnecessary do  this your app has surely rejected otherwise ok , this is not only for `citrus` payment gateway it is applicable for all `payment` gateways.

Answer (score 1):

> Apple Will accept the citrus payments

**Yes,** Apple allows (indeed, [requires](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html)) use of third party payment systems for purchase of real world goods and services.

One never likes to speculate about whether Apple will approve a given app, but your use of a reputable credit card processing service to let users pay for services such as cab rides will generally not be grounds for rejection.

Answer (score 0):

No you should never give CC details away EVER! But it depends on what you are doing with the payments. Please have a look at the following articles for clarification.

http://www.quora.com/Can-debit-credit-card-or-3rd-party-payment-be-used-for-iOS-In-App-Purchase-And-How

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

Comment: Thanks for Your Answere.We are Going to use  the payments for Cab bookings.

Comment: Sorry I accidentially skipped a line: 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected. So short answer: Rejected. Long answer: You could use apple their own API for IAP or Apple pay. there is enough documentation on apple their website.

Comment: @djkevino The rule you cite applies to in-app purchases, not payment for goods or services in the real world. Indeed, with respect to in-app purchase, Apple advises: [*Use a different payment mechanism to let your users buy real-world goods and services in your app, such as a credit card or payment service.*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html)